# What`s the best way to store shapes in a Database

Tags: java, mysql, shapes

I'am implementing an application that deals with Java Shapes. every user login and retrieve an inventory from a MySql Database. the shapes have differentes constructor and behaviore.

So, what the best way to store the shapes ? here is some of my ideas:

- Serialize the shape and store it as a Blob. but I would have a versioning issue if I have to change the Shape class, in adition of the big size of the DB and the query performance
- Make a Shape table with the common fields like the width and the height and a table for each shape which references to the Shape table. That could result in a lot of tables...
- Make a Shape table with all possible field and just put null for a shape that doesn't need the field...

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for the second solution because is easy to manage and extend. The serialization option is not practical because if the structure of the serialized model changes (example : adding an attribute), I have to manage the model versions. The third option is just not the right approach of building databases.

Answer (score 2):

Technically not an answer, but maybe the problem here is SQL? I'm thinking a document-storage system like CouchDB might be a much more effective solution for this scenario.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
{
    "_id": "whatever",
    "_rev": "whatever",
    "boundingBox": [
        [0 0],
        [2 2]
    ],
    "size": [2 2],
    "circle": {
        "center": [1 1],
        "radius": 1
    }
```

}

The `"circle"` stanza would change name and details depending on the shape. Rectangles would have the corners (similar to `"boundingBox"`), ellipsoids would have... Whatever defines ellipsoids :p

Answer (score 1):

Some simple ideas:

- You could store a list of vertices that define the polygon.
- You could store a list of vectors that define the edges of the polygon.

How they could be stored in a database:

- Master table of shape, with primary key an identity called "shapeID"
- Vector table, with a primary key identifying the vectorID, foreign key to the appropriate ShapeID, origin (x,y,z coords), direction (x,y,z), and length.

Additional meta data can be assigned to a shape with other tables that also reference the shapeID by foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a "best" way to store an inheritance hierarchy in a database.  There are 3 models that are taught in most database courses: Single Table with nulls, Table per SubClass, and Table per Concrete Class.  You can find a good explanation in [this blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/09/30/how-to-model-inheritance-in-databases.aspx).  You can choose whichever one of these that you prefer if you want to simply map the attributes of your shapes in the database.

If you want something more advanced to, MySql provides a [Geometry type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-class-geometry.html) that is specifically designed to store geometric shapes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd vote:

- Make a Shape table with all possible fields:

  - like the width and height
  - base and height
  - radius
    ...
  - shape type (e.g. 0= circle, 1= square, 3= triangle, ...)
- One table, all possible shapes, one shape instance/row

IMHO...

Q: How many different shapes do you think you might have?  How many columns do you think each shape might take?

PS:
A "polygon" (consisting of an arbitrary number of points) might merit two separate tables.  But most shapes (circle, ellipse, square, rectangle, etc) shouldn't need more than 4 or 5 columns/instance, and should easily fit in one table.